# Find the value of another group that gives maximum

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

This is my dataframe:

```r
df_test <- data.frame(Report=c("A-1","A-2","A-3","A-4","B-1","B-2"),grp=c("A","A","A","A","B","B"),defect=c("m","m","m","c","d","e"))
```

For each grp, I want to figure out the number of reports, and which defect contributes to the max value of the grp, and if there is a tie then I would like to output a collapsed value of the columns that tie.

Expected output:

```r
df_out<-data.frame(grp=c("A","B"),defect_list=c("m;c","d;e"),nreports=c(4,2),max_defect_list=c("m","d;e"),max_defect=c(3,1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be:

```
library(dplyr)

df_test %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  add_count(defect) %>%
  summarise(
    defect_list = paste(unique(defect), collapse = ';'),
    nreports = n(),
    max_defect_list = paste(unique(defect[which(n == max(n))]), collapse = ';'),
    max_defect = max(n)
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  grp   defect_list nreports max_defect_list max_defect
  <fct> <chr>          <int> <chr>                <int>
1 A     m;c                4 m                        3
2 B     d;e                2 d;e                      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`, we can also do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_test)[,  n := .N,  .(grp, defect)][, 
     .(defect_list = paste(unique(defect), collapse=";"), 
       nreports = .N, 
       max_defect_list =  paste(unique(defect[which(n == max(n))]), collapse = ';'),
       max_defect = max(n)), .(grp)]
#   grp defect_list nreports max_defect_list max_defect
#1:   A         m;c        4               m          3
#2:   B         d;e        2             d;e          1
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, I was wondering if you could please look at the new question I have posted since you have really good answers to the questions I have asked?

Comment: @Mel Will look into it.  Today, I am a bit busy.  Thanks

Comment: @Mel I find some solutions on your recent post.  I hope it is solved

Comment: Hi @akrun, I'm not sure if I see it. Thanks again for your time!